# React state not updating with new data being fetched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a `useFetchPokemon` hook that includes the following code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useFetchPokemon = () => {
  const initialUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]) as any;
  const [nextUrl, setNextUrl] = useState(null)
  const [previousUrl, setPreviousUrl] = useState(null)

  const getPokemonDetails = async (listOfPokemon: any) => {
    const pokemonWithDetails = await Promise.all(
      listOfPokemon.map(async (pokemon: any) => {
        const response = await fetch(pokemon.url);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
      })
    );

    return pokemonWithDetails;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInitalData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(initialUrl);
      const { results, next, previous } = await response.json();
      const pokemon = (await getPokemonDetails(results)) as any;

      setNextUrl(next);
      setPreviousUrl(previous);
      setPokemon(pokemon);
    };

    getInitalData();
  }, []);

  const getNextPokemon = async () => {
    if(!nextUrl) return
    const response = (await fetch(nextUrl)) as any
    const { results, next, previous } = await response.json();

    const newPokemon = await getPokemonDetails(results)

    setNextUrl(next)
    setPreviousUrl(previous)
    setPokemon(newPokemon)
  }

  const getPreviousPokemon = async () => {
    if(!previousUrl) return
    const response = (await fetch(previousUrl)) as any
    const { results, next, previous } = await response.json();

    const previousPokemon = await getPokemonDetails(results)

    setNextUrl(next)
    setPreviousUrl(previous)
    setPokemon(previousPokemon)
  }

  return { pokemon, nextUrl, previousUrl, getNextPokemon, getPreviousPokemon }
}
```

I then have a `PokemonList` component that uses the hook:

```js
import type { FC } from "react";
import { useFetchPokemon } from "../hooks/useFetchPokemon";

const PokemonList: FC = () => {
  const { pokemon } = useFetchPokemon()

  return (
    <div>
      Pokemon List
      <ul>
        {pokemon.map((p: any) => (
          <li key={p.name}>
            <img
              alt={p.name}
              style={{ width: "150px", height: "150px", objectFit: "cover" }}
              src={p.sprites.front_default}
            />
            <p>{p.name}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokemonList;
```

In my `App` component I have to buttons to fetch the next set of Pokemon and the Previous set:

```js
import PokemonList from './components/PokemonList';
import { useFetchPokemon } from './hooks/useFetchPokemon';

function App() {
  const { previousUrl, nextUrl, getNextPokemon, getPreviousPokemon } = useFetchPokemon();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {previousUrl && <button onClick={() => getPreviousPokemon()}>Previous</button>}
      {nextUrl && <button onClick={() => getNextPokemon()}>Next</button>}
      <PokemonList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click on the next button, the `getNextPokemon` call runs correctly and returns the correct data, but setting the new `pokemon` data to the state doesn't update the `PokemonList` component. I can't figure it out for the life of me...

Comment: Use proper types instead of casting everything to `any`. You won't regret it in the long run

Comment: Yeah, I plan on it  I put this together pretty quick and haven't spent the time typing the API responses yet. I was mainly having issues with the hook and wanted to quickly get help 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the **useFetchPokemon** hook in both the **<App />** and **<PokemonList />** components. This creates two separate instances of the hook, each with its own state. When you update the state in one instance of the hook, it doesn't affect the other instance.

You could try to use your **useFetchPokemon** hook inside **<App />** only and pass the required data to the **<PokemonList />** component through props.

**Plus:**

Also, if you would like to achieve "shared" experience, you can use React Context:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
// fetchPokemon here is your old one "useFetchPokemon" 
import { fetchPokemon } from "../fetchPokemon";

const PokemonContext = createContext(null);

export const useFetchPokemon = () => useContext(PokemonContext);

export const PokemonProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const pokemonData = fetchPokemon();
  return (
    <PokemonContext.Provider value={pokemonData}>
      {children}
    </PokemonContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

You just need to wrap up your components like that:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <PokemonProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <PokemonList />
      </div>
    </PokemonProvider>
  );
}
```

So you can access shared data inside the components:

```
import { useFetchPokemon } from "../context/PokemonContext";
...
const { pokemon } = useFetchPokemon();
```

Comment: This works and makes complete sense now! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
 const pokemon = (await getPokemonDetails(results)) as any;

  setNextUrl(next);
  setPreviousUrl(previous);
  setPokemon(pokemon);
```

> don't use **pokemon** name, first copy data to a new variable and then set it

```
const pokemon = (await getPokemonDetails(results)) as any;
const tempPokemon = pokemon
setPokemon(tempPokemon);
```

Comment: _"first copy data to a new variable and then set it"_... why?

Comment: Because in case of array or object state we should avoid mutating the state directly, instead you can create new copy of state with updated values and then call the setter function to update the state